# Как правильно спроектировать иерархию классов для сервиса OData (web api, C#)?

Tags: c#, api

Здравствуйте! Столкнулся с такой задачей и никак не могу решить. Есть Несколько бизнес объектов:

1. Персона (человек)
2. Организация
3. Адрес персоны
4. Адрес организации

Адрес персоны отличается от адреса организации несколькими полями.
Собственно вопрос в том, как организовать доступ к адресам?

Comment: доступ откуда?

Comment: Доступ из внешней среды к сервису web api odata. Например: к людям *api/odata/people, организациям *api/odata/organizations, а как отдельно к адресам, если их фактически два класса (*api/odata/addresses) или стоит ограничиться *api/odata/people/addresses и *api/odata/organizations/addresses